# Putting image between text

Tags: html, css, css-position

so I'd like to put 2 texts around an image (one text on the left, the other right of the image) and center them vertically. Is there other ways than putting `position:relative;` in the container and `position:absolute;` to the text (and play with the pixels of `top` and `left` to put it in the position that I want) to make the text and image RESPONSIVE in any devices? I want something like this:[image]

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<div class="socrates-words">
    <p class="hello"><strong>Hello!</strong></p>
    <p class="socrates-name"><strong>My name is Socrates.</strong></p>
  </div>
<div class="container-gif">
        <img src="/videos/socrates-video.gif" alt="" id="gif-socrates" />
      </div>
```

CSS

```
.button-section .container-gif {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 80%;
}

.button-section .container-gif #gif-socrates {
  transform: translate(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.button-section .socrates-words {
  font-size: 32px;
  position: relative;
}

.button-section .socrates-words .hello {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  top: 17rem;
}

.button-section .socrates-words .socrates-name {
  position: absolute;
  left: 65%;
  top: 17rem;
}
```

I'm doing my best and I'm a beginner so please no hate comments... Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello! Do you know about `display: flex` property?

Comment: Yes, I used it a couple of time but I have difficulties using it and to make it responsive... do you have any solutions?

Comment: If you are allowed to change your HTML, you can use the answer from Dev Rudra. If your HTML has to be the same, please write here and I will show a different solution

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to change your HTML.

This snippet uses a CSS grid of 3 equal columns, tells it to use the contents of the first child rather than the child itself (i.e. the 2 p elements) using `display: contents` and defines the order of the second p element within the grid and the img containing element.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  text-align: center;
}

.socrates-words {
  display: contents;
}

.socrates-words>* {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.socrates-words p:last-of-type {
  order: 3;
}

.container-gif {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="socrates-words">
    <p class="hello"><strong>Hello!</strong></p>
    <p class="socrates-name"><strong>My name is Socrates.</strong></p>
  </div>
  <div class="container-gif">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/50/100" alt="" id="gif-socrates" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Obviously you can alter various dimensions to suit your particular requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy example of how you can do it.
just place your image in between the text container and then using **display flex** you can achieve the result you want.
It is also responsive.

**Explanation**

> I used *display: flex;* so I can align all the image and text in a row.

> I used *justify-content: space-evenly;* to make the space between the image and test even

> I used *align-items: center;* to make all the text and the image to center from top and bottom.

```css
.socrates-words{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="socrates-words">

    <p class="hello"><strong>Hello!</strong></p>

    <div class="container-gif">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1672002760123-4c6496489053?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=60" alt="" id="gif-socrates" />
    </div>

    <p class="socrates-name"><strong>My name is Socrates.</strong></p>
    
  </div>
```

**I hope you got the answer and also got how it works!**