# Wordpress - Insert icon next to text

Tags: wordpress, svg, frontend, icons, text-alignment

I'm new to this frontend area (freelance backend) and I needed some help. I simply need to put that WhatsApp icon before the phone... But I'm taking a hell of a chorus (missing Java... lol)

Can someone give me a help???? With this code the visualization is like this...

[image: view image]

```
[icon name="theme-screen-smartphone" style="" color="accent1" size="50" ]
<h1>ATENDIMENTO VIA<strong> WHATSAPP</strong></h1>
<h4>Tire suas dúvidas e remarque suas
sessões com muito mais facilidade!</h4>
<h5>Clique no telefone e para tirar suas dúvidas: <a href="http://Link Do WhatsApp" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><strong>31 9 9999 9999</strong></a></h5></br>

<svg aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
<symbol id="icon-whatsapp" viewBox="0 0 190 190">
<path d="M27.281 4.65c-2.994-3-6.975-4.65-11.219-4.65-8.738 0-15.85 7.112-15.85 15.856 0 2.794 0.731 5.525 2.119 7.925l-2.25 8.219 8.406-2.206c2.319 1.262 4.925 1.931 7.575 1.931h0.006c0 0 0 0 0 0 8.738 0 15.856-7.113 15.856-15.856 0-4.238-1.65-8.219-4.644-11.219zM16.069 29.050v0c-2.369 0-4.688-0.637-6.713-1.837l-0.481-0.288-4.987 1.306 1.331-4.863-0.313-0.5c-1.325-2.094-2.019-4.519-2.019-7.012 0-7.269 5.912-13.181 13.188-13.181 3.519 0 6.831 1.375 9.319 3.862 2.488 2.494 3.856 5.8 3.856 9.325-0.006 7.275-5.919 13.188-13.181 13.188zM23.294 19.175c-0.394-0.2-2.344-1.156-2.706-1.288s-0.625-0.2-0.894 0.2c-0.262 0.394-1.025 1.288-1.256 1.556-0.231 0.262-0.462 0.3-0.856 0.1s-1.675-0.619-3.188-1.969c-1.175-1.050-1.975-2.35-2.206-2.744s-0.025-0.613 0.175-0.806c0.181-0.175 0.394-0.463 0.594-0.694s0.262-0.394 0.394-0.662c0.131-0.262 0.069-0.494-0.031-0.694s-0.894-2.15-1.219-2.944c-0.319-0.775-0.65-0.669-0.894-0.681-0.231-0.012-0.494-0.012-0.756-0.012s-0.694 0.1-1.056 0.494c-0.363 0.394-1.387 1.356-1.387 3.306s1.419 3.831 1.619 4.1c0.2 0.262 2.794 4.269 6.769 5.981 0.944 0.406 1.681 0.65 2.256 0.837 0.95 0.3 1.813 0.256 2.494 0.156 0.762-0.113 2.344-0.956 2.675-1.881s0.331-1.719 0.231-1.881c-0.094-0.175-0.356-0.275-0.756-0.475z"></path>
</symbol>
</defs>
</svg>

<svg class="icon icon-whatsapp"><use xlink:href="#icon-whatsapp"></use></svg>
```

[image: I would like it to stay this way...]

**CSS CODE**

```
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  stroke-width: 0;
  stroke: currentColor;
  fill: currentColor;
}

/* ==========================================
Single-colored icons can be modified like so:
.icon-name {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: red;
}
========================================== */
```

Regards...

Comment: Can we see your css code?

Comment: I'm using a pre-defined theme from Wordpress itself... I didn't configure a specific CSS file... The theme I'm using is Fitness Sport Gym Child By Vamtam =(
I used the IcoMoon App to generate an icon font. Download the generated icon font and upload the ZIP archive... I will attach the file to serve as a reference

Comment: You will have more flexibility with what you're trying to accomplish if you use CSS. Maybe you can try to put the WhatsApp logo in between the text and phone no. in the code?

Comment: I did a double check on the zip file and I found the CSS configuration that the IcoMoon App generates... I just appended it in the body of the code.

I'm new in this area of ​​front... actually I'm just doing a freela to help a friend.

How can I put the WhatsApp logo between the text?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74923219/putting-image-between-text

Comment: Try this: put the svg icon in the needed position and use 'viewBox="0 0 32 32"' for both the symbol and the svg class="icon". Do not forget to give a width to the .icon and make sure it has display: inline